# Automapper 4.2.1 LINQ projections work only with static Mapper.CreateMap?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, automapper, automapper-4

I'm trying to use Automapper projections on Entity Framework IQueryables.

On application start, I create and add all my mapping profiles which create maps with the non-static CreateMap method.

All those profiles are registered within my IoC container.

I get the missing mapping exception although I see the mapping profile in the instance of my mappingConfiguration.

What could be the problem? Am I missing something? I'm using Automapper 4.2.1

I've noticed that when adding a static Mapper.CreateMap, it works fine. Do projections work only with static API? I want to avoid the static API.

Full code:

```
public class ItemEntityToItemView : Profile
{
    public override void Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<ItemEntity, ItemView>();

        // Without this line, I get missing Map type configuration.
        Mapper.CreateMap<ItemEntity, ItemView>();
    }
}


public interface IEntitiesProjector
{
    IQueryable<T> SelectTo<T>(IQueryable source);
}

public class EntitiesProjector : IEntitiesProjector
{
    private readonly IMapperConfiguration _mapperConfig;

    public EntitiesProject(IMapperConfiguration mapperConfig)
    {
        _mapperConfig = mapperConfig;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> SelectTo<T>(IQueryable source)
    {
        return source.ProjectTo<T>(_mapperConfig);
    }
}

public class ItemsRepository : IITemsRepository
{
    public IQueryable<ItemEntity> GetById(int id)
    {
        return _dbSet.Where(x => x.Id == id);
    }
}

public class Service
{
    private readonly IEntitiesProjector _projector;

    public Service(IEntitiesProject entitiesProjector)
    {
        _projector = entitiesProjector;
    }

    public List<T> GetItem(int id)
    {
        IQueryable<ItemEntity> itemsQueryable = ItemsRepository.GetById(id);

        return _projector.SelectTo<ItemView>(itemsQueryable);
    }
}

My Autofac registration :

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes().AssignableTo(typeof(Profile)).As<Profile>();

builder.Register(c => new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<IdentityUser, AspNetUser>().ReverseMap();
})).AsSelf().As<IMapperConfiguration>().SingleInstance();

builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<MapperConfiguration>().CreateMapper(c.Resolve)).As<IMapper>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

builder.Register<EntitiesProjector>().As<IEntitiesProjector>().SingleInstance();
```

Comment: post your code sample

Comment: Added my profile.. is it supposed to work? Or is it known that projections work only when using the static API?

Comment: When I use `ProjectTo()`, I have to add a generic type parameter and provide a mapper configuration as parameter. You have neigher of those in your very incomplete question code. Btw: I'm using `using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;` in order to get my `ProjectTo` overload extensions

Comment: Then again, I'm using AutoMapper 4.2.0 here, maybe 4.2.1 has additional overloads

Comment: I added the full code. I'm using Automapper 4.2.1, Automapper.QueryableExtensions, and Autofac. Hopefully you understnad and can help me solve this!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason is the following block:

```
public class EntitiesProjector : IEntitiesProjector
{
    private readonly IMapperConfiguration _mapperConfig;

    public EntitiesProject(IMapperConfiguration mapperConfig)
    {
        _mapperConfig = mapperConfig;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> SelectTo<T>(IQueryable source)
    {
        return source.ProjectTo<T>(_mapperConfig);
    }
}
```

`source.ProjectTo` is an extension method which has 5 overloads. In documentation they are passing instance of `MappingConfiguration` class there, and you are passing instance of `IMapperConfiguration` (interface). You think it will have the same effect, but it does not. `IMapperConfiguration` interface does not implement `IConfigurationProvider` interface, and that (`IConfigurationProvider`) is what correct overload of `ProjectTo` accepts. But, there is another overload of `ProjectTo`, which accepts "`object parameters`". Because it accepts object - it will match anything which did not fit other overloads. So what you are really calling is `ProjectTo(object)` overload, which has nothing to do with configuration, and your `IMapperConfiguration` together with profiles and maps is completely ignored.

Quickfix will be

```
public class EntitiesProjector : IEntitiesProjector
{
    private readonly IConfigurationProvider _mapperConfig;

    public EntitiesProjector(IMapperConfiguration mapperConfig)
    {
        _mapperConfig = (IConfigurationProvider)mapperConfig;
    }

    public IQueryable<T> SelectTo<T>(IQueryable source)
    {
        return source.ProjectTo<T>(_mapperConfig);
    }
}
```

But of course you should better register your configuration as `IConfigurationProvider` in your container, that is just quick fix to ensure problem is really here.

As for static `Mapper.CreateMap` - well it's static, so works regardless of what you pass to `ProjectTo`.

As a side note this shows you how to not design api. Whenever you have many overloads and one of them accepts generic object and does *completely* different thing than all other overloads - that is asking for trouble.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks!